80-meter sprint competition
We have an 80-meter sprint competition. Should I teach a low start without starting blocks?
If yes, is the low start without blocks similar in movements and technique to the traditional low start with blocks?

Who is "we" in this context, specifically are you the one responsible for setting the rules and regulations of the competition?
